# SQL Server combines CREATE/ALTER and EXEC

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

When you get an error and you get a message in SSMS with the line of code it occurs, you'll want to find the content of that line.

But I came across a bug.
If you run the following code on SQL Server, you'll get a recursive function call. It looks like the ALTER accepts the EXEC as part of the stored procedure, even though it's after the AS BEGIN...END line.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_GetErrorLine(
    @lineNum INT, 
    @spName NVARCHAR(250)
) AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    CREATE TABLE #spLine (
        line INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
        Bob NVARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #spLine (Bob)
        EXEC sp_helptext @spName

    DECLARE @line NVARCHAR(2048)

    SELECT @line=Bob FROM #spLine
        WHERE line=@lineNum

    DROP TABLE #spLine;

    SELECT @lineNum AS [Line No.], LTRIM(RTRIM(@line)) AS [SP Line]
END

EXEC SP_GetErrorLine 67, 'SP_AnotherProcedure'
```

(You'll need to run it with SP_AnotherProcedure replaced to any other stored procedure you have in the same DB.)

Is this expected behaviour, or is it mis-parsing the code?

Cheers

Comment: BEGIN/END is not batch terminator. What you are experiencing is exactly how it should behave. If you want to have multiple scripts you need to put the batch separator in between batches. The default batch separator is GO. Not an answer to your question but you might look at this article. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: To further illustrate Sean's point, take out the `BEGIN` / `END` (they're not necessary). The stored procedure still gets created. SQL Server sees `END` as the end of a block, not the end of a procedure, so anything after it will also be part of the procedure.

Comment: Ah, thanks @SeanLange, didn't know that performance tidbit. Time to do some renaming.

Comment: The thing that had me puzzled was it accepted `AS BEGIN ... END` without complaint, and there's a requirement for functions to use `BEGIN...END` if they're multi-lined, so I assumed that was the case here.
Can you use BEGIN/END without an `IF (X)` or `AS` before it, for scoping or whatever? (I come from C++ where you can use `{}`s that way)

Comment: Yes you can use any number of them too. It only demarcates code blocks which is not the same thing as a batch.

Comment: @SeanLange That explains things then! If you'd make an answer about that, I'd mark it as accepted (so you get the points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEGIN/END is not batch terminator. What you are experiencing is exactly how it should behave. If you want to have multiple scripts you need to put the batch separator in between batches. The default batch separator is GO.

That being said you can have any number of BEGIN/END blocks in a single batch. The real trick is not confusing a batch with a block.

Comment: It's also worth noting you can't do `BEGIN END` with no statements in between -- that's seen as incorrect syntax near END, which might explain why I didn't realise `BEGIN/END` could be used without conditions prepended.